# OpenSSH on Windows does not add private key when user certificate is present

Tags: windows, ssh, certificate, openssh

I am having problems adding a private key with a user certificate to the `ssh-agent` with OpenSSH on Windows. When I try to add a key with `ssh-add testkey` and there is also a user certificate available for this key like `testkey-cert.pub`, only the certificate is added to the `ssh-agent`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new RSA key pair `ssh-keygen -f testkey`
2. Create CA key pair for signing the test key `ssh-keygen -f ca`
3. Sign the test key `ssh-keygen -s ca -I testkey testkey.pub`
4. Add test key to SSH agent `ssh-add testkey`
5. List added keys to check result `ssh-add -l`

Only the `RSA-CERT` was added to the agent.

```
PS C:> ssh-add testkey
Identity added: testkey (testkey)
Certificate added: testkey-cert.pub (testkey)

PS C:> ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:vaqqEObTRX5icClKdRsEvyut5G1ug9C8uBjJ1TrCx9w testkey (RSA-CERT)
```

When I do these steps on Linux, the RSA key **and** cert are both added

```
$ ssh-add test
Identity added: test (test)
Certificate added: test-cert.pub (id_rsa)

$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:3bhXQ3lSdSejjvecm2XtMBa46XiyqFaC70pLibgILMo test (RSA)
2048 SHA256:3bhXQ3lSdSejjvecm2XtMBa46XiyqFaC70pLibgILMo test (RSA-CERT)
```

Is this an issue with the OpenSSH client for Windows?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: A workaround solution to add the private key with additional 'dot' in key file: `ssh-add test.`  It should be related to [1954](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1954)

Comment: You can also add the private key only to ssh-agent: `ssh-add -k test`

Answer (score 1):

Doing some necromancy:
I stumbled over the same problem.

My solution:
move the cert out of the folder
ssh-add private_key
move the cert back in .ssh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).